# How to determine the level using following rules

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array which looks like the following

```
$levels = array(P, P, F, F, P)
```

P is PASS, F is FAIL.

There are five levels, represented by the array index.

I have to determine the level using following rules.

> Rules:
>
> 1. The current level must be passed to move to the next.
> 2. Lowest Passed level should be considered as the actual level.

In the above example. The actual level should be calculated as 2. The last P will be ignored because the previous levels are not passed.

In another example, if data looks like following

```
(P, F, P, F, P)
```

The actual level should be 1 (if the array index starts from 1). The lowest passed level.

I have come so far but the code might look a bit different. I explained the problem as an isolated system. The reason was to avoid some confusions and complications.

```
$result = array();
foreach($answers as $att=>$level){
    foreach($level as $key=>$val) {
        if (in_array("0", $val))
            $result[$att][$key] = 0;
        else
            $result[$att][$key] = 1;
    }}
for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++){
        if($result[$i][$j]==1)
            $attribute.$i = $j;
        else 
            continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, we should write code for you, right?

Comment: I don't see any question mark - what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($levels); $i++){
   if($levels[$i] == "F"){
      $actual_level = $i;
      break;
   }
}

echo $actual_level;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to php.net there is plenty of function for arrays, and there is a nice [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), which returns the first matching key. As this will be the first 'F', you need to substract 1 to have the preceeding key. If your levels begin at 1, no need to substract 1.

This will work even if there is no 'F' in the array.

```
$levels = array('P', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'P');

$firstFailed = array_search('F', $levels);

// Instead of 5 use the var holding your max level.
echo $firstFailed ? $firstFailed : 5;
```